# Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+ <a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project

Tags: windows, android-sdk-tools, android-studio-2.2

Ever since I downgraded my Android Studio (Windows) from 2.3.3 to 2.2.1 I'm getting an

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+

It is suggesting me to update my Android Studio to the latest version. But is there any way I can continue using version 2.2.1 withhout any need to add some references every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that the repositories are set up correctly

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

**Try**

[image: Install Repository and Sync project]

**Install Repository and sync project**

This will fix most of the issues.

Comment: How to install install the repository??